# Presenting Modal View Controller programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog

In the main screen of my iOS application I have a table view populated with a list of users from a web service, what I want to do is to show the table, and over it a modal view controller. I have everything set up, but I don't know how to present my "ModalVC" programatically from the main screen, and to do it after the table was populated? The code below is for presenting a normal view controller programmatically.

```
let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ModalVC")
self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
```

Comment: Though this may be a duplicate, it is not a duplicate of the linked question: "Instantiate and Present a viewController in Swift"

Answer (score 39):

Presenting a view controller of class name ModalVC programmatically

```
let modalVC = ModalVC.instantiateFromStoryboard(self.storyboard!)
self.presentViewController(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Swift 3:

```
let modalVC = ModalVC.instantiateFromStoryboard(self.storyboard!)
self.present(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Swift 5: self.present(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)